# How do I level up in Pillars of Eternity?

Tags: pillars-of-eternity

In my log I saw a message saying I had earned enough experience points to level up! But I can't work out how to do it... I looked in the Character tab, where I expected to find it, but no such luck.

How do I level up?

Comment: One does not simply... ah, forget it.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Click on the golden cross in your character portrait, exactly the cross, not the portrait itself.

[image]

Comment: Somebody should tell the devs that icon's really easy to miss. I have trouble finding it even when I'm aware there's been a level-up.

Answer (score 18):

There's a small golden + on the bottom left of the screen during normal adventuring.

[image: Red freehand circle indicating where it is]